# How to get data regarding facebook page mentions via facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried getting data using Graph API Explorer code below:

**GET request:**
**page_id/tagged**

But I'm getting only few posts. I created 2 new posts from 2 different users and tagged my page. I get mentioned notifications in my page, but it doesn't reflect in graph API.

Is there any other way to track page mentions or Am I doing it the wrong way? Also, I need the user id of the user who has tagged my page.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? I'm confused.

Comment: Your problem may be due to security.  Do the 2 different users have public profiles or have the 2 users granted your app access?  At least one must be true for you to see the post via the API.

Answer (score 0):

I was using user access token. I used Page access token, now I'm getting the data.